# Multer Req.files.path not editable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm currently trying to change the path of multiple files in req.files.path with Multer file uploads, but the paths don't seem to want to change. Here's my code:

```
app.post("/api/imageUpload", upload.array("uploadedImages"), function(req, res) {
    req.files.forEach(function(file) {
        file.path.replace(/\\/g, "/").substring("public".length);
        console.log(file.path);
    });
    res.status(200).send({files: req.files});
});
```

The original path of my files looks something like public\uploads\filename.

This code is attempting to replace the backslashes in the path to forward slashes. When I console.log the path, nothing changes. Nothing changes when I res.send the files over to the browser with an AJAX call either (and when I try to change the paths in my JS file with the .replace method, it still doesn't work). I have other parts of code where Multer is only uploading one file and the path is able to change just fine; however, I am assigning the path to a variable, so that may be where the issue lies. I'd just like to know if that's the issue (and if so, why?)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `replace()` string function does not mutate the string. If you want to replace the string, use this:

```
req.files.forEach(function(file) {
    file.path = file.path.replace(/\\/g, "/").substring("public".length);
    console.log(file.path);
});
```

Comment: Ah -- I knew it was going to be something simple. Thanks very much for this; I'm sure it will work, but I'll test once I get home and let everyone know.

Comment: No problem... Pls upvote and accept this as the answer if it solves the problem...

Comment: @AaronMarsden Were u able to resolve the issue...??